# Flutter 1.17.1 update problems on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

After I update Flutter to the version 1.17.1 and Dart to 2.8.1 I started to get this following error on iOS:

```
io.flutter.1.raster (8): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

I tried to change the channel to master and do a flutter clean, but that didn't work. I also tried to use some of the other versions of flutter that are on the dev channel but I keep getting the same error. The only way I can successfully run my app is downgrading to flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 that I was previously using. My Xcode is also updated to the latest version, 11.4.1.

Anyone else is having this problem and/or know how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe a longshot but you could check this: https://gitmemory.com/issue/flutter/flutter/56302/624919454
Another option would be to create an issue in the flutter repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the same as the link posted in the comments by MyrackeDesign. The extension for iOS, FlutterViewController, caused the problem, when I removed it, the app ran normally.